# Rails: Erratic secondary post request after redirect_to action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an occasional problem where there seems to be a secondary post request rails after the redirect to index.

The following behavior is happening 95% of the time:

```
Started POST "/update_workorder" for 172.16.92.73 at 2015-03-27 08:13:57 -0700
I, [2015-03-27T08:13:57.709649 #11686]  INFO -- : Processing by R5EventsController#update_workorder as HTML
I, [2015-03-27T08:13:57.710186 #11686]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"CFuQjQ6jpJCTMqAjLhz1ZBLXdfIB8lnkjsJOO1f857w=", "stuff"="data"}
I, [2015-03-27T08:13:59.344661 #11686]  INFO -- :   Rendered pm_mailer/default_email.html.haml (9.0ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:14:00.024827 #11686]  INFO -- : 
Sent mail to people@email.com (534.2ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:14:00.028079 #11686]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://eambeweb/r5_events
I, [2015-03-27T08:14:00.028283 #11686]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 2318ms (ActiveRecord: 1203.3ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:14:00.297247 #11686]  INFO -- : Started GET "/r5_events" for 172.16.92.73 at 2015-03-27 08:14:00 -0700
I, [2015-03-27T08:14:00.298461 #11686]  INFO -- : Processing by R5EventsController#index as HTML
I, [2015-03-27T08:14:00.469535 #11686]  INFO -- :   Rendered r5_events/index.html.haml within layouts/application (163.0ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:14:00.476018 #11686]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 177ms (Views: 72.5ms | ActiveRecord: 101.5ms)
```

But sometimes some how, some times the starting GET, it starts a POST:

```
Started POST "/update_workorder" for 172.16.92.73 at 2015-03-27 08:17:35 -0700
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:35.176066 #11702]  INFO -- : Processing by R5EventsController#update_workorder as HTML
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:35.176583 #11702]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"CFuQjQ6jpJCTMqAjLhz1ZBLXdfIB8lnkjsJOO1f857w=", "stuff"="data"}
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:35.981182 #11702]  INFO -- :   Rendered pm_mailer/default_email.html.haml (9.4ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:36.565325 #11702]  INFO -- : 
Sent mail to people@email.com (445.9ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:36.568528 #11702]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://eambeweb/r5_events
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:36.568737 #11702]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 1392ms (ActiveRecord: 448.3ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:38.567563 #11702]  INFO -- : Started POST "/update_workorder" for 172.16.92.73 at 2015-03-27 08:17:38 -0700
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:38.569935 #11702]  INFO -- : Processing by R5EventsController#update_workorder as HTML
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:38.570403 #11702]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"CFuQjQ6jpJCTMqAjLhz1ZBLXdfIB8lnkjsJOO1f857w=", "stuff"="data"}
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:39.001262 #11702]  INFO -- :   Rendered pm_mailer/default_email.html.haml (7.7ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:39.639698 #11702]  INFO -- : 
Sent mail to people@email.com (637.7ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:39.640420 #11702]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://eambeweb/r5_events
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:39.640662 #11702]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 1070ms (ActiveRecord: 414.4ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:39.851618 #11702]  INFO -- : Started GET "/r5_events" for 172.16.92.73 at 2015-03-27 08:17:39 -0700
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:39.852857 #11702]  INFO -- : Processing by R5EventsController#index as HTML
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:40.091512 #11702]  INFO -- :   Rendered r5_events/index.html.haml within layouts/application (227.0ms)
I, [2015-03-27T08:17:40.098016 #11702]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 245ms (Views: 70.1ms | ActiveRecord: 172.0ms)
```

My update_workorder method:

```
def update_workorder
    # .... horrifying amount of lines
    PmMailer.default_email(workorder["org"],workorder,assets,current_user,lines).deliver
    if workorder["priority"] != '0' and !workorder["priority"].nil?
      PmMailer.send_email_with_higher_priority(workorder["org"],workorder,assets,current_user).deliver
    end
    redirect_to action: "index"
end
```

Nothing particularly special about my form:

```
= form_tag("/update_workorder", method: "post") do
  -# terrible terrible
  %br  
  .row-fluid
    .col-xs-12
      %br/
      %input{:type=>"button", :value=>"Back to My Workorders", :style=>"margin-bottom:10px;width:240px;height:50px;font-size:1.5em", :onClick =>"history.go(-1);return true;"}
      %input{:type=>"submit", :value=>"Save", :style=>"margin-bottom:10px;width:240px;height:50px;font-size:1.5em;margin-left:50px"}
```

Comment: In the `#update_workorder` method, won't that send two emails if the workorder meets the conditional's criteria?

Comment: Also, are these just production logs? Could it be that someone submitted the form normally, then pressed their browser's back button, and started to submit a second form, but instead hit the `"Back to My Workorders"` button, which would tell their browser to resubmit their previous `POST` request?

Comment: Well the problem is not the email, but the secondary POST. I've thought about that, being something that does not happens all the time. What methods can i use to prevent this user interaction?

Comment: Well, like I said, it's just a guess, but you could try and rule it out by redirecting to the explicit path of the user's workorders instead of using `:onClick =>"history.go(-1);return true;`.

For example:
`<%= button_to "Back to My Workorders", user_workorders_path(current_user), :method => :get  %>`

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to replicate the problem using the current back button but it does not seem to generate the problem

Comment: Try submitting the form, then hitting your browser's back button until you are back to the form entry you just submitted, then hit the actual `Back to My Workorders` button. If that doesn't generate the problem then I'm wrong and it's something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob W. was completely correct. The problem was not the application itself but users playing around with the back and save buttons. I did four things to the form:

- As per Rob W. suggestion i changed the back button behavior
- I added a auto refresh function via javascript if the user came to this form using the back button
- I disabled the save button after submitted
- I added a small history of recent transactions to show the users that the action was already performed.